# Piecewise Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process time integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a piecewise Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with infinitesimal variance $\sigma^2$ and (piecewise) infinitesimal mean $\theta_1$ for $x<c$ where $c$ is a constant and $\theta_2$ for $x\geq c$.

In other words, $X_t$ is the solution to the equation
$$ dx_t = -\theta_1 x \mathbb{1}(x_t<c)\,dt - \theta_2 x \mathbb{1}(x_t\geq c)\,dt + \sigma \, dW_t. $$
This process is known as a piecewise OU process because of the piecewise structure in the mean term.

Let $Y_t = \int_0^t X_s \, ds$ be the time integral of $X_t$. I want to characterize the variance of $Y_t$ which from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84952/time-integral-of-an-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process) is straightforward once I characterize the covariance $Cov(X_s, X_u)$.

I have the derivation of the covariance for an OU process from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) but I don't know how to derive this for a piecewise OU process. Is this function a known result? Alternatively, if I want to derive this, how would I go about doing so? Thanks for your help.

**Edited:** Clarified that I want to characterize the variance of $Y_t$.

Comment: (i) What do you mean by "solve for $Y_t$"? (ii) By $x1$, do you mean $x_t1$?

Comment: one suggestion is to try to work with exit times eg. if $X_{0}=1$ and $c>1$, we can study $X_{t\wedge \tau_{c}}$ because ,I think, it will be related to a regular OU (but I might be missing something).

Comment: @IosifPinelis I edited to clarify that I want to characterize the variance of Y_t. By x1, are you referring to the differential equation? If so the 1(x_t<c) is an indicator variable.